# Center a text in layout limiting the left size with another view

Tags: android, layout, center, gravity

Let me explain this, need to center a tex according to the parent, but taking in account a view to the left of the layout:

```
|------------Screen--------------|
[View]    [Short Text]

|------------Screen--------------|
[View][Loooooooooooooooooong Text]
```

Using relative layout gravity property i only getting this:

```
|------------Screen--------------|
[View]       [Short Text]          <------THIS IS WRONG.

|------------Screen--------------|
[View][Loooooooooooooooooong Text]
```

Thanks in advance

The question is about how to make the layout. There is no code to start with it can be done anyway (of course not using a fixed value for the width of the view), i was actually doing it with relative, but had no luck.

Now if you really want something from the scratch, now i'm using the suggestion of @Padma Kumar

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:src="@drawable/something" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **Let me explain this** - Yes, it would be useful if you did explain it but you haven't. Without a layout and/or Java code (and a better explanation) it's impossible to tell what you're asking.

Comment: @desgraci I am not getting whats your actual problem? BTW in the ImageView what is the use of android:layout_centerVertical="true"?

Comment: @PadmaKumar the issue is if i try to center the textview in lets say a relative layout, it will center on the screen, but for long texts it will go over the view to the left, i want it to dont go over the view to the left, like toRightOf, ofc if i use this attribute it wont be centered anymore, is hard to explain with words, and there are a lots of combinations of layouts that can show this issue that is why i dint include any at the beginning. To center a TextView horizontally on screen and not going over the view in the left. P.D. the centerVertical, just centers vertical it can be removed:D

Answer (score 1):

put your 2 views in linear layout

//use `android:layout_Weight`

for your view give weight as '0 '
for your shorttext view give weight as '1' and gravity as left.

this will work fine

Comment: It did not work, cause the shorttext is always next to right of the view.

But it works when the text is very long, it holds up again the view.